# alter table drop foreign key ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, drop

`mysql> alter table orders_testorder drop foreign key 'orders_testorder_confirmed_icdo_dx_id_33d3fe14_fk_orders_ic';`

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''orders_testorder_confirmed_icdo_dx_id_33d3fe14_fk_orders_ic'' at line 1`

The name is correct.  This is standard syntax.

Why does this not work?

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes

Comment: That's right. You don't put table, column, index, constraint, etc. names in quotes.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: yes, mysql does not use "standard" syntax; if identifiers are quoted, it needs to be in backticks, not single quotes

Comment: Please post complete TEXT output of SHOW CREATE TABLE orders_testorder;  so we know what your are dealing with.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.